# square connect API list inventory with item id

Tags: square-connect

I'm using this example to get the inventory list:

```
try {
    $result = $api_instance->listInventory($location_id, $limit, $batch_token);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling V1ItemsApi->listInventory: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

I would like to create a items/products list out of it but I can't since it only returns "variation_id" and "quantity_on_hand". How can I get the item_id so I can retrieve the necessary details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item was created using the Square Dashboard, or via V2's `UpsertCatalogObject` then it will be a V2 catalog object. With the V2 object, you can use the `RetrieveCatalogObject` endpoint and pass the `variation_id` directly to get the variation's details (which includes `name`, `price`, and `item_id`).

If you used V1 `CreateItem` then it will be a V1 item, and the only way you can find the `item_id` using the `variation_id` would be to `ListCatalog` (or V1 `ListItems`) and loop through to find the item with the corresponding `variation_id`.

References:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-catalog

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#navsection-items

Comment: Is possible can i integrate using API for inventory, so that if order placed by website automatically inventory down with squareup app and vice versa? @sjosey

Comment: If you create an order with an item, and then call `Charge` with that order, the inventory will automatically be reduced.

Comment: Sure, take a look here to see how to add an order to a transaction: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/cookbook/orders-and-transactions

Comment: Thank you, and make sure squareup App API support for Magento.

Comment: Unfortunately, Square does not create the integrations with partners, so it is up to Magento to add functionality to their integration.